# Greyscale image to binary image conversion using operations on pixel

Tags: image-processing, digital-image-processing

Previously, I tried convert a color image into a greyscale image by using pixel values of an image from a simple formula :-

```
Grey = 0.3*Red + 0.58*Green + 0.11*Blue
```

After that, I wanted to convert the greyscale image into a binary image & I used two different techniques :

***NOTE :*** Red, Green & Blue are variables storing Greyscale intensity of the Pixel.

***1. Algorithm 1:***

```
if Red <= 127:
   Red = 0
   Green = 0
   Blue = 0
else:
   Red = 1
   Green = 1
   Blue = 1
```

***2. Algorithm 2:***

```
if Red <= AvgIntensity:
   Red = 0
   Green = 0
   Blue = 0
else:
   Red = 1
   Green = 1
   Blue = 1
```

where, **AvgIntensity** represents the average intensity of all the pixels of the image.

(Obviously,) the algorithms turned out to be wrong, producing incorrect output. So, I wanted to know about the correct way for greyscale to binary image conversion.

Comment: What is the purpose? what do you expect to find when changing to binary image?

Comment: Experimentation.

Comment: I mean, what is the "correct" output?

Comment: You may want to look for *error diffusion*. Other than that, the answer may be as simple as `Red = Green = Blue = 255` (seeing that you compare to 127). Better yet, *don't use magical literals*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [thresholding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)) algorithm.  There is no correct or incorrect algorithm.  Some methods tend to work better than others on specific types of images; which method is best may depend on what kind of images you usually work with. I suggest studying standard thresholding methods and picking one.